# Is it possible to copy files with exception rules with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 related questions about Azure:

1. Is it possible and how can we setup a copy of file with **exception**. Actually, I would like to copy all my file **except** the config files during deployment.

As you see I copy `**`. How can I tell this system I want to copy `**` except `*.config` files?

[image]

2. Because this question 2 can result on debate I will ask it in another space. Is it correct, in .NET, to try to deploy all files without config file? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/394466/21623

Comment: usual way of ignoring something is adding `!` in front of it, try: `!*.config`

Comment: I want excluding/including files by substring or other patterns you can try out the result with http://www.globtester.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `!*.config`:

```
**
!*.config
!**\*.config
```

The third line is for config files that exist in sub folders.

You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files) the full syntax.

Comment: Thank you. And I realize now if I use this option I cannot clean my destination folder.

Comment: Why you can not?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Robocopy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jungeriusit.jungit-robocopy), you can use exclude files under options.

[image]